# Add a whole column with values to the SQL table

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe

I have a SQL table and have made it a dataframe with Python.

Then I calculated new values for a new column.

As you know, it's easy to add new columns with values to a dataframe as long as the length of the dataframe and the added column is the same.

Now I can take the whole dataframe and make a new MySQL table.

`df.to_sql(name=key+".1", con=engine , if_exists ='fail', index=False)`

But it seems a bit too complicated to me to do it this way.

So I tried to insert the values into the new table by using

```
# for index,x in enumerate(df["Time"]):
        #     try:
        #         mycursor = mydb.cursor()
        #         mycursor.execute("UPDATE "+key +" SET DhE="+str(df["DhE"][index])+" WHERE Time='"+str(x)+"'")
        #         mydb.commit()
        #     except:
        #         print("UPDATE "+key+" SET DhE="+str(df["DhE"][index])+" WHERE Time="+str(x) +"****error ")
```

This is not usable.

1. The "WHERE" clause compares the datatype Date() as the primary key of the table, which was a bad choice.
   Don´t do this, this is a unique key but not usable in practice.
2. By default, a where clause is way too slow for a table length of 731911 to add values for a whole column.

My conclusion and my question are
Do I have to write a whole new Table into my database, or is there a way to just add the Column (with values!), which has the same length as the table, to the MySQL Table ?

for example, using

`INSER INTO XY.new_Column VALUES "whole new column values"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are inserting values into the MySQL table is very inefficient. It iterates through each row and updates it one by one. This results in a very high number of individual queries to the database, which is extremely slow.

1. Connect to your database.
2. Use `ALTER TABLE` to add the new column.
3. Bulk insert the values using `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.
4. Commit the changes.

In Python, this should work.

```
import pymysql

# Connect to database
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='username', password='password', database='mydb')
cursor = connection.cursor()

# Add new column
cursor.execute("ALTER TABLE your_table ADD new_column_name datatype")

# Bulk insert values (assume values_list contains (time, value) tuples)
query = "INSERT INTO your_table (Time, new_column_name) VALUES (%s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE new_column_name=VALUES(new_column_name)"
cursor.executemany(query, values_list)

# Commit and close
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Replace `your_table` with your table name, `new_column_name` with the column name, and `datatype` with the column's datatype. Also, have `values_list` as a list of tuples with the time and value for the new column.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answer.

I got a warning,

that VALUES function' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use an alias (INSERT INTO ... VALUES (...) AS alias) and replace VALUES(col) in the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause with alias.col instead .

I changed it to:

```
query = "INSERT INTO your_table (Time, new_column_name) VALUES (%s, %s) AS x DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE new_column_name=x.new_column_name)"
```

In addition, the "time" column has to be the primary key so I set

```
ALTER your_table
MODIFY COLUMN TIME datetime NOT NULL
```

and

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD PRIMARY KEY (Time)
```

After that, sql is able to get an key error and DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE can do its magic.

Now I will go to benchmark this against adding the whole new table :)